# How accomplish Phonegap auto login?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I need my app to automatically log in a user if the localstorage of username and password are set. how would i do this? via ajax or what? i'm planning on loading the site they need to login to remotely, via an iframe, so that i can load phonegap plugins and other things when the app loads.

what would be the best way to automatically log people in? any code would be greatly appreciated.